# Extending the MembershipUser class

Tags: orm, membership-provider

I am extending the MembershipUser and MembershipProvider classes. I am using an ORM.

I am wondering - the MembershipUser class has no Password property, yet there are methods that return its password and change its password and so on. I had first thought that, using the ORM approach, we could do:

```
user.password = newPassword;
session.commit();
```

But it seems that the MembershipUser is not supposed to have any password property or field and instead it must be set via SQL (so will have to create the query)?

To make my question clearer:

If the MembershipUser class has a password field, I could do something like this in the updatePassword method of the MembershipProvider:

```
User user = from database.getUser(username, oldpassword);
user.password = newPassword;
session.commit();
```

But if I can't have a password field, I have to use SQL:

UPDATE password SET.. etc etc... as I can't get and change OBJECTS from the database as the objects don't have the fields I need to change (such as the password field).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a wrapper class around the MembershipUser with all virtual fields that could be manipulated. I created a ToMembershipUser method to satisfy the MembershipProvider methods.

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating your own derivative of the MembershipUser class, you should already be thinking about creating your own MembershipProvider.

Your exact question is unclear, but if you implement your own membership provider you will need to implement (primarily) they "Validate" and "GetUser" methods which will allow you to instantiate and user your custom MembershipUser instance.

Comment: Yes but inside those methods I cannot get MembershipUser objects from the database as is the ORM approach, as the MembershipUser has no password property.

Comment: you can add a password property if you want, but you should rethink your authentication approach.  Typically, If I need a connection object that requires the actual password, I construct it during or soon after the Validate method, when I have the password "in-hand", and put it in a place accessible to the rest of the app.